# AdaptiveIconDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable

Tags: java, android

Getting this error in android Oreo in One plus device

```
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mIconFile);
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) mAppIcon;
        Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable

Comment: Think of color object as another JSON, inner JSON. and parse it as you do `message`

Comment: @Vipin Your json string contains some errors.

Comment: Json should be like this `{
  "message": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "thickness": "102mm",
      "description": "jkdshfjkdshjkghkj",
      "guarantee": "1 year",
      "color": "[{\"QMW3WBeV\":\"White\",\"SWW23sdf\":\"5\"},{\"QMW3WBeV\":\"Cream\",\"SWW23sdf\":\"0\"},{\"QMW3WBeV\":\"Maroon\",\"SWW23sdf\":\"6\"},{\"QMW3WBeV\":\"Grey\",\"SWW23sdf\":\"4\"}]"
    }
  ]
}`

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not correct and for JSON parsing, you can use GSON Parser.
Tutorial is in the following line https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Comment: i done it  String color=jsonObject1.getString("color");
                                    color=color.replace("'\'","");
                    JSONArray jsonArraycolr=new JSONArray(color);
                  for (int j = 0; j < jsonArraycolr.length(); j++) {
      JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArraycolr.getJSONObject(j);
jsonObject2.getString("QMW3WBeV"); jsonObject2.getString("SWW23sdf");
                                       }